# Percentage in WHERE CLAUSE in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause, percentage

I want to get all records have price 20% Less OR More of a give value.

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| ID | Item        | Category |  price  |       
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Popular     | Rock     |  1000
|  2 | Classical   | Opera    |  5000 
|  3 | Popular2    | Jazz     |  6000
|  4 | Classical2  | Dance    |  8000
|  5 | Classical3  | General  |  4825
+----+------------+----------+------------+
```

User has to pass two parameters

i - Category

ii-Price

I need to show all item having same category and price is between 20% less and 20% greater than user's value.
Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Categry='ROCK' AND price > (20% less price of user's price) AND price < (20% greater than user's price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `@price` represents the user's price:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  Categry='ROCK' AND price BETWEEN (0.8 * @price) AND price < (1.2 * @price)
```

Comment: can you explain it,how you using .8 and 1.2?

Comment: @user3244721 0.8 (i.e., 80%) is 20% less than a whole (=1). 1.2 (or 120%) is 20% more than a whole (=1). Once you have this ratio down, you can multiply it by the size (in our case `@price`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Categry='ROCK'
    AND price > (userprice * 0.8)
    AND price < (userprice * 1.2)
```

Comment: you have used 4/5 and 5/4?why so?

Comment: better to use 0.8 and 1.2

Comment: why it is 0.8 and 1.2?why not same degits?either 1.2 or 0.8

Comment: as i understand you need 80% between 80% and 120%